# image_map in Pov-ray not working as expected

Tags: image, mapping, raytracing, imagemap, povray

I would like to map an image I have to the face of a box in Pov-ray.

The image's dimensions are 1500x1125
([Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9nGd.png))

So I set up a scene with a light source above a camera looking at a box

```
camera{location <3,1.8,0> look_at <3,1.8,1>}
light_source{<3,20,0>  color rgb <1,1,1>}
box{<0,0,0> <1,0.75,1> texture{pigment{image_map{png "Test1.png"}}} translate <2.5,1.425,3>}
```

The box's dimensions are 1x0.75 (z not relevant) which has the same 4:3 ratio as the image.

However, when the scene is rendered, the width of the image maps perfectly onto the box but some of the height is cut off. The image does not look stretched and I am confused why it does not fit.

Comment: how does the vertical and horizontal field of view look like (aka fov parameter?)

Comment: Can you provied the "Test1.png" file?

Comment: @Vertexwahn Sorry for late reply. The test1.png image is the example image link in the question. Also I am new to Pov-Ray and do not know how to find the fov parameter

Comment: Could it be that you see only 0.75 * texture_height. Is it possible to provide uv coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, porvray will always read images as if they had a 1:1 aspect ratio.
If you insert a scale inside your pigment statement, before using it, that should fix it:

```
box{
   <0,0,0> <1,0.75,1> 
   texture{
       pigment {
           image_map{png "Test1.png"}
           scale <1, 0.75, 1>
       }
   } translate <2.5,1.425,3>
}
```

(I apologize for not testing this to be really sure right now).

Comment: Sorry for the late response but thank you! I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere.